# File to Array to Struct

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I'm working on this program that is to help manage a DVD rental store. What I have to do is take a text that contains info about DVD etc:

Mean girls; comedy; PG; 2009; Regina George; 12.07.2015;

The Conjuring; Horror; R; 2013; Sara Johnson; 16.05.2016;

Pokemon 2000; Kids; G; 2000; Ash Katchem; 15.04.2016;
etc..

And then takes this information and then reads it into an array and from there the array is read into the struct and then displayed in proper order like so: 
Name: Mean Girls 
Genre: Comedy
Rating: PG

etc...

This is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct dvd{
        string name;
        string genre;
        string rating;
        string released;
        string renter;
        string rentday;

        void print();
        bool read(ifstream & file);

};

void dvd::print(){
        cout <<"Title: " << name << endl;
        cout <<"Genre: " << genre << endl;
        cout << "Rating: " << rating << endl;
        cout << "Release date: " << released << endl;
        cout << "Name of renter: " << renter << endl;
        cout << "Date rented: " << rentday << endl;
    }
bool dvd::read(ifstream & file)
{
    getline(file, name, ';');
    getline(file, genre, ';');
    getline(file, rating,';');
    getline(file, released, ';');
    getline(file, renter, ';');
    getline(file, rentday, ';');
    return file.good();
}
int main() {
    vector<dvd> dvds;
    dvd         dvd1;
    ifstream file("DVD.txt");

    if(! file.is_open()){
        cout << "Failed to find input file" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    while(dvd1.read(file))
    { dvds.push_back(dvd1);
    }

    dvd1.print();


return 0;

}
```

So what I would like to do is have read the text file into the Array and from there read the Array into the struct. So instead of the text file reading into the vector I need it to read into the array and from there read the first line of the array (dvdArray[1]) into struct dvd and then print out that information using print function and then loop that until dvdArray[10] is read into struct dvd!

Thank you so much for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
bool dvd::read(ifstream & file)
```

to

```
bool dvd::read(istream & file)
```

No other changes to its contents are required.

Then, take each line and put it into a `std::istringstream`, then pass it to `dvd::read`.

You should be able to figure out the rest on your own.

Comment: Okay so I've got the text file reading into the Array but I can't seem to figure out how to read this into dvd::read while printing out each dvd info

Comment: Like I wrote: construct a `std::istringstream` from a given line, then just pass it.

Answer (score 0):

For simple reading from and writing to file, I would suggest overload `<<` and `>>` for your struct class, in order to make the code easy to serialize and de-serialize in a readable fashion.

```
friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const dvd& dvdObj) 
{
  // your output stuff
  // stream <<"Title: " << dvdObj.name << endl;
  // ...
  return stream;
}

friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& stream, dvd& dvdObj) 
{
   // your output stuff
  // getline(stream, dvdObj.name, ';');
  // ...
  return stream;
}
```

Then,

```
// look for std::copy for reading directly into vector ... else 
while( file >> dvd1 )
{ 
   dvds.push_back(dvd1);
}
```

And,

```
for( const auto& dvd1: dvds )
{
  std::cout << dvd1 ;
}
```